# RegEx not working for long pattern PCRE's JIT compiler stack limit - PHP7

Tags: php, regex, less, php-7

I am using oyejorge's less compiler.

```
list-style-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
```

traps an Exception. I narrowed it down, and I created a test script

```
$regex = '/\\G"((?:[^"\\\\\r\n]|\\\\.|\\\\\r\n|\\\\[\n\r\f])*)"|\'((?:[^\'\\\\\r\n]|\\\\.|\\\\\r\n|\\\\[\n\r\f])*)\'/';

$image = '"data:image/gif;base64,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");';

$a = preg_match($regex, $image, $b);

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

This works an php 5.5 and 5.6, but result array is on some php7 hosts empty.
Any idea why?

Comment: `preg_match` returns false which indicates an error. Have you checked out the PHP7 migration guide?

Comment: I cannot find anything related in the migration guide. Also, I don't think it returned false, but 0.

Comment: It does for me on 3v4l.org

Comment: PHP 7 introduces PCRE's JIT compiler. It can affect whether/how inefficient regexes are executed on long inputs. you can disable it by using `ini_set('pcre.jit', false);`. for detail have alook at my answer

Comment: The answer is actually usual: write efficient regexps! :)

Comment: Actually, I do not get it what you want to match with this regex. If you explain what it is meant to match, there could be a better answer than "turn off that "RegEx UAC" off" :)

Comment: As I said, it is from the less compiler library, to parse the url("data..."), but that's the regex which causes problems...

Answer (score 12):

PHP 7 introduces PCRE's JIT compiler. It can affect whether/how inefficient regexes are executed on long inputs.

https://3v4l.org/Y58It

```
Error 6 = PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR
```

Rewrite the regex to be more efficient, typically by removing extraneous capturing groups or being more careful with quantifiers.
As a workaround you can disable JIT.

https://3v4l.org/Y1pja

so you can make it work by using below solution:

```
ini_set('pcre.jit', false);
print_r(ini_get_all('pcre'));

$regex = '/\\G"((?:[^"\\\\\r\n]|\\\\.|\\\\\r\n|\\\\[\n\r\f])*)"|\'((?:[^\'\\\\\r\n]|\\\\.|\\\\\r\n|\\\\[\n\r\f])*)\'/';

$image = '"data:image/gif;base64,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");';

$a = preg_match($regex, $image, $b);

//var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump(preg_last_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

PCRE JIT uses a 32K machine stack by default (you can change this at PCRE compile time, but people rarely do that). This can be extended to any maximum by using the JIT stack interface. If this interface is supported by PHP, they likely provide a configuration for that. If not it is worth requesting a support for it.

Blame windows for this complexity. If everybody would use pthreads, there wouldn't be such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is terribly inefficient. Regex101.com had your original at **4702 steps**, but adding a little possessiveness brought that down to **20**. [Proof.](https://3v4l.org/Akc9Z#output)

```
$regex = '/\\G"((?:[^"\\\\\r\n]++|\\\\.|\\\\\r\n|\\\\[\n\r\f])*)"|\'((?:[^\'\\\\\r\n]++|\\\\.|\\\\\r\n|\\\\[\n\r\f])*)\'/';
```

**TL;DR:** Don't use configuration to work around bad regexen.